# Problem with the basis of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation

I have this exercise

```
 Define and find the expression of the linear transformation
```

> Information given:
>
> $ T : \Bbb R^5\to \Bbb R^4$
>
> Im T = ⟨(3, -1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 1 -1)⟩
>
> ⟨(3,3 0, 0,0)⟩⊂ Ker T

```
Solve T(⟨(1; 1; 0; 0); (0; 0; 1; 0)⟩) and give a basis.
```

I have already  define the transformation and found the expresion that  is 
T(x,y,z,w,u)=(x-y+z,-x+y,w,x-y+z-w)
And T(⟨(1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0)⟩)  that is 
T(1,1,0,0,0)=(0,0,0,0)

T(0,0,1,0,0)=(1,0,0,1)

> But I  have a problem giving the basis, is the transformation basis the
>   imagen basis,I don't really undestand what is the problem asking in that part?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you denote `SubGen`?

Comment: Thanks,generated subspace.

Comment: The usual name is the Span. And I suppose `c Ker T` means `contained in Ker T`?

Comment: Yes,i suppose it is that.

Comment: (SubGen(1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0))  could also be written like this <(1, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 0)>

Comment: Yes I like that latter notation. The way to make a nice $\langle$ and $\rangle$ in mathjax is to write \langle and \rangle.

Comment: Also the trick for writing a nice $\subset$ in stead of c is typing \subset

Comment: Thanks I edited it,know it looks better :)

Comment: What do you mean by "basis of the linear transformation"? I know what bases of vector spaces are but not what you mean by one of a linear transformation.

Comment: That is exacly my question,I dont understand what the problem is asking me, by telling me to give a basis of T(⟨(1; 1; 0; 0); (0; 0; 1; 0)⟩).I also know what bases of vector spaces are,but I dont really know if the problem is asking me for  that.

Comment: As I understand it, iIt asks  for a basis of the image by $T$ of the subspace generated by $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,0)$ (the image of a subspace by a linear map is a subspace). The problem is that these vectors are not in the domain of $T$ since the have only $4$ coordinates.